# Creating nested comments in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, react-native

I am working on a React Native project with Nested comment section.
Comments are fetched as JASON data and rendered through a FlatList.

```
export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getQuestions = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://..../api/q/289');
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
  }, []);


  const addCommentReply = () => {
    var newData = [
      {
        "qid": "540",
        "aid": "540",
        "content": "New Comment/Reply",
        "privacy": "true",
        "uid": "23",
        "name": "Jhone",
      },
    ];
    setData(data.concat(newData));
  }


  return (
    <Screen>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ qid }, index) => qid}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <AppCommentReply content={item.content} uname={item.name} />
          )}
        />
      <CommentBox>
        <Button title="Add element" onPress={addCommentReply} />
      </CommentBox>
    </Screen>
  );
};
```

1. Is FlatList a correct approach for a nested comment section?
2. With {addCommentReply} i can add a comments to the main array stream. but when someone is replying to a comment, to render replies, I'm thinking of pushing that data just below the corresponding "qid" in the array. How to push data into the middle of the array?

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator is helpful to insert an element into array:

```
function insert(arr, index, item) {
  return [
      ...arr.slice(0, index),
      item,
      ...arr.slice(index)
 ];
};
```